# Apache, Docker, Proxy - change adress in browser to 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, proxypass

I have Apache server with few sites.

I would like to run on this server docker container with Mercure and share it on the Internet.

I found information on the Internet that I need to use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in the vhost configuration.

My vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tomaszf.pl
    ServerAlias www.tomaszf.pl

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mercurytest/public

    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/html/mercurytest/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /var/www/html/mercurytest/public/bundles>
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tomaszf.pl.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tomaszf.pl.log combined
 
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.tomaszf.pl [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =tomaszf.pl
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName tomaszf.pl
    ServerAlias www.tomaszf.pl

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mercurytest/public

    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/html/mercurytest/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /var/www/html/mercurytest/public/bundles>
        DirectoryIndex disabled
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tomaszf.pl.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tomaszf.pl.log combined

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/tomaszf.pl/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/tomaszf.pl/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    ProxyPass /mercure http://127.0.0.1:8099/
    ProxyPassReverse /mercure http://127.0.0.1:8099/
</VirtualHost>
```

Docker container is launched with the command:

```
docker run \
    -e SERVER_NAME=':80' \
    -e MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY='!ChangeMe!' \
    -e MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY='!ChangeMe!' \
    -p 8099:80 \
    -e CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS='https://tomaszf.pl' \
    -e DEBUG=1 \
    -e ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1 \
    dunglas/mercure caddy run -config /etc/caddy/Caddyfile.dev
```

Problem:
When you try to enter the website tomaszf.pl/mercure, the address in the browser is automatically changed to 127.0.0.1 and website not working.

What do I have to change in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the same configuration, with the exception of a self-signed certificate and modifying my hosts file to point `tomaszf.pl` to `127.0.9.1` and I'm **not** being redirected off of that host.

[image: curl response]

That proves that the latest version of the container `dunglas/mercure:latest` from dockerhub is redirecting correctly. If you are having issues with this, verify you have the latest image (hash `c10597bdf077` for amd64 at the time of writing).

The other issue you are going to face is that the caddy module `mecure` **does not** appear to support serving the module anywhere but the root of the host (i.e. `tomaszf.pl` only, **not** `tomaszf.pl/mercure` ). This seems to be a design decision based on the use of the `/.well-known` prefix (Mercure Caddy Module documentation https://caddyserver.com/docs/modules/http.handlers.mercure)

I would recommend using a subdomain (perhaps `mercure.tomaszf.pl`) and serve the module from there, at the root, instead.